# Making groovy @Log annotation safeguard calls inside closures

Tags: groovy

**EDIT**: [GROOVY-6932](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-6932) was logged and has now been closed - the problem is marked as fixed in Groovy v2.4.8.

I use the @Slf4j annotation to add a logging to my groovy classes.

I like it because of the AST transformation that wraps my log calls inside an "enablement" check, documented [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Logging)

What I've found though, is that the guard clause doesn't work if the log method is called from within a closure.

Running on Groovy 2.2.0, this code logs only one message, but prints "called" twice.

```
@Grapes([
  @Grab(group='org.slf4j', module='slf4j-api', version='1.7+'),
  @Grab(group='ch.qos.logback', module='logback-classic', version='1.+')])
import groovy.util.logging.Slf4j

new TestCode().doSomethingThatLogs()

@Slf4j
class TestCode {
  void doSomethingThatLogs(){
    log.info createLogString(1)
    log.trace createLogString(2)
    Closure c = { log.trace createLogString(3) }
    c()
  }

  String createLogString(int p){
    println "called with $p"
    return "blah: $p"
  }
}
```

I've tried adding "this", "owner" and "delegate" specifiers to the log statement but same result.

The context I found this in was when I was trying to log some nodes using XmlUtil.serialize while parsing XML with XmlSlurper.

I'm working around the problem by wrapping the NodeChild object in a lightweight object with a toString() method that calls the XmlUtil class.  That'll work fine and the overhead of the extra wrapper classes is not worth worrying about.  I'm more interested in finding a simple way around this problem so that I can go back to not having to think about the cost of construction of logging messages when they aren't being logged anyway.

The question I'm asking: is there any way to have the logging level guard clause work properly within closures, instead of having to add the "log.traceEnabled" calls myself?

Comment: Try adding delegate to the log statement: delegate.log

Comment: I tried your example, this is pointing to the class TestCode, I checked also the source for the Slf4j annotation. In my opinion it should work, so I think you should file a Groovy issue. I am sorry that I was not able to help.

Comment: do you have the same problem if you use `@Log4j`?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the generated code in a decompiler (IntelliJ has one built in now, or use something like Jad) - it might help to see what's being generated by the AST transforms.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick thought. How will you know what `log.traceEnabled` will be on closure execution? See the modified example ...

```
@Grapes([
        @Grab(group='org.slf4j', module='slf4j-api', version='1.7+'),
        @Grab(group='ch.qos.logback', module='logback-classic', version='1.+')])

import groovy.util.logging.Slf4j
import jline.internal.Log
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Level;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger;

new TestCode().doSomethingThatLogs()

@Slf4j
class TestCode {
    void doSomethingThatLogs(){

        log.info createLogString(1)
        log.trace createLogString(2)
        Closure c = { log.trace createLogString(3) }
        Logger root = (Logger)LoggerFactory.getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
        root.setLevel(Level.TRACE);
        c()
    }

    String createLogString(int p){
        println "called with $p"
        return "blah: $p"
    }
}
```

Now at the time the closure is created `log.traceEnabled` is false, but when the closure is executed this had changed.

The output is:

```
called with 1
16:53:15.408 [main] INFO  TestCode - blah: 1
called with 3
16:53:15.414 [main] TRACE TestCode - blah: 3
```

Note the second `TRACE` is still not printed :-)

Comment: I don't actually know, but I had assumed that Groovy was generating the same kind of code that you would write manually - that is, surrounding the log statements with generated bytecode for "if log.isDebugEnabled()".  Are you saying you think Groovy is eliding the bytecode at compile/load time?

Comment: Sorry ... I was not on the topic. I dug into detail but could not understand all the logic behind the scenes (Groovy!?) Some observations though: 1. Because Groovy is dynamic it is not all 'bytecode', but metaclasses and some hidden magic.  2. If you look at the [@Slf4j](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/groovy/src/main/groovy/util/logging/Slf4j.java) code you can see that the 'wrapping' is made with TernaryExpression / isTraceEnabled? log... : NULL / which is called dynamically 3. However when this is in Closure this call is preserved, but it comes after evaluating the argument and ...

Comment: ... thus your method is called. However you are right ... it looks like a BUG!